# How do I align my button to the center of the page?

Tags: html, css, button, alignment, text-alignment

I am trying to align the button to the center of the page, (instead of the left side)
But here is all i'm getting:

[image]

```css
.btn1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #1E90FF;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 60%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  float: right;
}

.btn1:hover,
.btn1:focus,
.btn1:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn1">Show me a note!</button>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you with HTML and relevant frameworks

Comment: You haven't specified left or right - Something like `left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%)` should center it horizontically

Comment: Also you want flex on the container, not the button

Answer (score 0):

By giving button a specific height and width will take the button on the center of the page

```css
.btn1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
background: #1E90FF;
width: 500px;
height: 66px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
padding: 20px;
border-radius: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn1">Show me a note!</button>
```

Comment: width: 500px;
height: 66px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;

by giving button a specific height and width  will take the button on the center of the page.